# Access Spark Web UI on port 4041

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, spark-webui

I have launched a single node GCP compute engine ( n1-standard-4) and installed spark 3.4.1.

I'm trying to access spark web UI from chrome browser in mac using http://<compute- engine - instance-ip>:4040. Tried both internal and external IP of compute engine.

WebUI via Internal IP does not work.

```
http://<internal-ip-of_compute-engine>:4040.
```

Hence tried from external IP, only port 4040 works, can see webUI from port 4040, not from 4041. From the spark job logs, I can see that few of the jobs have been tagged to port 4041 ie. "Service SparkUI could not bind on port 4040. Attempting port 4041. Successfully started service SparkUI on port 4041".  When I try to access webUI as below,getting the message "This site can’t be reached. <external-ip-of_compute-engine> refused to connect."

```
http://<external-ip-of_compute-engine>:4041
```

Questions:

1. Given I can see webUI from 4040 from same host, are there any other changes I need to configure to see webUI from port 4041? tried to check firewall rules using 'gcloud compute firewall-rules list', do not see mention of both 4040 and 4041.
2. When I run other spark job and explicitly set spark.ui.port=4040 during session creation, still I can see in logs "Service SparkUI could not bind on port 4040. Attempting port 4041. Successfully started service SparkUI on port 4041". what could be the reason for this as no other jobs are running on the cluster? can we release port 4040 before the job, so that job can use that.

Comment: "could not bind on port 4040" means one thing only -- some other process is bound to it. Perhaps you can confirm it by running `netstat -nlpt | grep 4040`; if you're root you'll be even able to see what this process is.